# How to remove blank pages after each page in pdf view ( rdlc report )

Tags: pdf, visual-studio-2012, report, rdlc

I am using RDLC report in visual studio 2012. Report seems great when view in browser but in PDF view, blank page is attached after each report page.I have been to various links but they did not work for me.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just decrease the size of your RDLC report page, it will not add additional page in PDF.

Comment: yes, I have done it,now it is working fine. Well thanks for your help :)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830944/empty-pages-in-rdlc-report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just decrease the size of your RDLC report page, it will not add additional page in PDF.
(This answer is copy pasted from the comments and added as an answer because as it seem to fix the problem)

Comment: did you mean reducing the page size in report setting or reducing the size of components in report??

Comment: You may have to decrease the size of components to reduce the size of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by changing the margins in page properties.
The page had 0,5cm in each side, so I removed, and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the root cause for my problem was due to the size of the body of the report. The size of the body cannot be larger than the report itself. So, I have reduced the width of the body of the report to be 6cm smaller than the report itself, and this for landscape page.