# Empty blank page at the end of RDLC report

Tags: rdlc

I have RDLC report that has various controls on it (tablix, textbox, page footer, image etc). Data is being rendered and this report is converted to an pdf file. When the report ends rendering content at the last line or at very end of last page, a new blank page gets rendered / appended at the end of the report. If the report ends some where in middle of the page, blank page is not rendered at the end. This only happens when the page content ends at the last line of the last page.

I tried implementing below **[1]** common solutions that people have provided on various forums. But this blank page issue still persists.

Following is my Report and Body size. Am I missing something else here?
Report Page size -> Width - 8.5in; Height -> 11in
Report Margin -> Left, Right, Top, Bottom -> all 1in

Body Size -> Width - 6.5in; Height -> 6.97916in

**[1]**
1. Set ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace = True
2. Body Width <= Page Width - (Left Margin + Right Margin)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483181/how-to-remove-blank-pages-after-each-page-in-pdf-view-rdlc-report/38570393#38570393

Comment: I set the Page-Height to 10.9in but this still didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that we had a tablix control at the end of the report. That tablix report had an empty row added at the end. This empty row was causing report viewer to add blank page at the end when ever the data content was ending at the last line of the page. I applied conditional visibility to that row and we now don't see that blank page at the end.

We can now mark this thread as closed.